# CustomPaint with animation: avoid recreating object

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Suppose I have an object

```
class LogoDrawer extends CustomPainter {

   int x;
   
   LogoDrawer(this.x){
      print('New logoDrawer object created');
      _initStuff();
   }

   void Paint(Canvas canvas, Size size)
   {
      _paintStuff();
   }
}
```

And value of `x` changes externaly through an animation and the `_initStuff` method may be expensive but is not dependend on the value of `x`.

If I would then animate it with an `_onClick` method

```
class _SomeState extends State<SomeWidget>  with TickerProviderStateMixin {

    x = 0;

    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return GestureDetector(
                child: CustomPaint(
                  willChange: true,
                  painter: LogoDrawer(x)
                ),
                onTap: _onClick,
              );
    }

    void _onClick() {
        _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
        vsync: this,
        );

        animation = Tween(begin: 0.4, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _controller, curve: Curves.ease, reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut))
        ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
                x = x+1;
            });
        });
        _controller.forward().orCancel;
    }
}
```

This technically does work but the console keeps printing

> New logoDrawer object created

quite often (not on every redraw). And this implies that initializations are redone also very often which takes quite a toll on the resources. I would actually want to create the object once, change the value of `x` through the animation and only issue redraws and not creating new objects. What I had in mind was creating the custom painter once and update its internal value, but that does not seem to trigger repaints

```
class _SomeState extends State<SomeWidget>  with TickerProviderStateMixin {

    x = 0;
    var myPainter = LogoDrawer(x);

    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return GestureDetector(
                child: CustomPaint(
                  willChange: true,
                  painter: myPainter
                ),
                onTap: _onClick,
              );
    }

    void _onClick() {
        _controller = AnimationController(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: animDuration),
        vsync: this,
        );

        animation = Tween(begin: 0.4, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _controller, curve: Curves.ease, reverseCurve: Curves.easeOut))
        ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
                x = x+1;
                // OR 
                painter.x = x+1;
            });
        });
        _controller.forward().orCancel;
    }
}
```

Note that this is a generic description of my problem and that the real code I am working with is far more complex than this.

Comment: check `repaint` parameter of `CustomPaint` constructor

Comment: alternatively mix your `CustomPainter` with `ChangeNotifier` - see the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) for more info

Answer (score 0):

May be it is possible to use the **shouldRepaint** method to trigger redraw only if some variable has changed like in this example : [Flutter analog Clock](https://medium.com/@ouzarinacime/flutter-analog-clock-coding-with-custompaint-7819b3f73fd0)

Comment: That would still trigger a new object creation instead of a repaint. I would rather do something like `myPainter.setDateTime(now)` and then do something like `myPainter.repaint()` but the latter unfortunately does not exist

Comment: @WouterVandenputte so does it mean that `repaint` parameter of `CustomPainter` does not work?

Comment: well, I do not know exactly. It is quite a complicated application. there is a `State` which calls `onClick` and then creates an animation with a random duration such that a specific part of the painter rotates, but not the entire painter. But I would have to give this animation before creating my `FooPainter`. Once this animation is done, the rotation should just continue from where it is, so no reset to a new object with an initial rotation of zero radians

Comment: a new `onClick` then creates a new animation but how do I pass that new animation to the existing `FooPainter`? I can only create a new instance and not update it `repaint` argument

Answer (score -1):

What you could do is create a class that holds all the data that you initialize and initialize that once in your state and pass it to your painter. That way you have a new painter instance each time, but don't need to initialize it, as that data is passed in.

Alternatively, you could put that data into `static` members and have a static initialization method of your custom painter class. For example, in one of my projects I have two painters you can switch between, one that just fills with different colors and one that uses textures. Since all textures need to be loaded, that is not done on every switch, but instead once in the splash screen.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about that too but there is quite some logic in the painter that I would have to refactor. I was simply hoping that there is an easy solution to issue redraws through `setState`

Comment: @nvoigt there is a built-in solution in `CustomPainter` already: `repaint` parameter used in `CustomPainter` constructor

Comment: @pskink Sounds good, why not make an answer from that?

Comment: @pskink I do not seem to find this `repaint` paramter in the constructor. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html

Comment: @WouterVandenputte see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter/CustomPainter.html - it reads: *"The painter will repaint whenever `repaint` notifies its listeners."*

Comment: okay acccording to the doc <Extend this class and supply a repaint argument to the constructor of the CustomPainter, where that object notifies its listeners when it is time to repaint.>

but that implies that `CustomPainter` would have to notify listeners, which it can't? I could really be helped with an example because the documentation does not provide any help on that field. I know `CustomPainter` inherits from `Listenable` but it only provides methods to add listeners, not to call hem

Comment: @WouterVandenputte all you need is to call `super(repaint: ...)` for example:  `class FooPainter extends CustomPainter {
final Animation<Color> animation;

FooPainter(this.animation) : super(repaint: animation);

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
canvas.drawRect(Offset.zero & size, Paint()..color = animation.value);
} ...`

Comment: @pskink thanks, it seems there was a problem regarding the package as there are 2 instances of `CustomPainter`. One in `widgets` and one in `rendering`. That's why I was unable to call that constructor

Comment: @WouterVandenputte in `widgets` you have `CustomPaint`, while in `rendering` you have `CustomPainter`